# Extract span content fi match

Tags: php, regex, dom

I'm fetching a website with this code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML($output);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach($tables as $table)
{
  $div = $table->getAttribute('class');

  if( $div == "ppfundove" )
  {
    echo $dom->saveHTML($table)."<br />";
  }

}
```

and this is the return html.

```html
<div class="ppfundove">
<div style="float:right;">
  <div style="width:120px;height:180px;margin:0 0 5px 5px;border:solid 0px black;">
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- MdP Linhas --><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:120px;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-0625882597391969" data-ad-slot="6701994172"></ins>
    <script>
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- MdP Linhas --><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:120px;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-0625882597391969" data-ad-slot="6701994172"></ins>
    <script>
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ppindent">
  <div>Distrito: <span class="ppredib">Porto</span>
  </div>
  <div>Unid. Estat. (NUTS III): <span class="ppredib">Tâmega</span>
  </div>
  <div>Província: <span class="ppredib">Douro Litoral</span>
  </div>
  <div>Freguesias: <span class="ppredib">Bonfim, Campanhã, Paranhos, Ramalde, União das Freguesias de Aldoar, Foz do Douro e Nevogilde, União das Freguesias de Cedofeita, Santo Ildefonso, Sé, Miragaia, São Nicolau e Vitória, União das Freguesias de Lordelo do Ouro e Massarelos.</span>    </div>
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
```

I need to get:

> Bonfim, Campanhã, Paranhos, Ramalde, União das Freguesias de Aldoar, Foz do Douro e Nevogilde, União das Freguesias de Cedofeita, Santo Ildefonso, Sé, Miragaia, São Nicolau e Vitória, União das Freguesias de Lordelo do Ouro e Massarelos.

If  was preceded by "Freguesias: "

How can i do that using DOMDocument class?

Comment: 1) We're not here to do your work for you. Try yourself, show us what you've tried and ask for specific help on specific parts you have issue with. 2) Don't use regex to parse HTML, use something like `DomDocument`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$con ='<div>Freguesias: <span class="ppredib">Bonfim, Campanhã, Paranhos, Ramalde, União das Freguesias de Aldoar, Foz do Douro e Nevogilde, União das Freguesias de Cedofeita, Santo Ildefonso, Sé, Miragaia, São Nicolau e Vitória, União das Freguesias de Lordelo do Ouro e Massarelos.</span>    </div>';

preg_match_all('/<div>Freguesias:\s*<span class="ppredib">(.*?)<\/span>\s*<\/div>/i', $con, $array);
print_r($array[1][0]);
```

OR

```
preg_match('/<div>Freguesias:\s*<span class="ppredib">(.*?)<\/span>\s*<\/div>/i', $con, $array);
print_r($array[1]);
```